# Why is this representing the left tail?

Tags: copula, joint-distribution

In this [source](http://ww.qjps.com/media/Journal-Article-PDFs/0800000005.pdf) about the Clayton copula on page 18 they write:

> It has been used to study correlated risks because it exhibits
>   strong left tail dependence and relatively weak right tail dependence.
>   Anecdotal and empirical evidence suggests that loan defaults are
>   highly correlated during recessionary times. Similarly, researchers
>   have studied the “broken heart syndrome” in which spouses’ ages at
>   death tend to be correlated. When correlation between two events, such
>   as performance of two funds or spouses’ ages at death, is strongest in
>   the left tail of the joint distribution, Clayton is an appro- priate
>   modeling choice.

Now, I am not understanding, why these examples mean, that the left tail is correlated? Why is the spouses' ages at death the left tail? And why is recessionary times the left tail? Is it, because in resessionary times negative returns occur and this is representing the left tail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is the spouses' ages at death the left tail?**

I would disagree with the authors statement. I guess that spouses' deaths are equally correlated over their joint distribution. It doesn't make sense that younger couples tend to die together rather than older couples. This is what a Clayton-copula would model.

**And why is recessionary times the left tail? Is it, because in resessionary times negative returns occur and this is representing the left tail?**

This one is easier. The text mentions, that loan defaults are highly correlated. Just assume that a big company defaults in a small town. Therefore it can't pay its liabilities anymore. Probably other companies go bankrupt because they are dependent on this cash inflow. Or the now unemployed can't afford the same life style as before and restaurants go bankrupt.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why are the loan defaults on the left tail? Or: What does the left tail means in this context and why is it not the right tail? I am not getting this.

Comment: I assume that the book models the returns of loans and not the loss. That's the key point. Loans which default have low returns since everything you get back is your collateral. In an univariate distribution that models a loan's return, the default scenario is in the left tail.
In contrast, comon books model the loss of loan where the default risk is in the right tail.